# Define protected abstract interface method as abstract in abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, interface, abstract-class, default-interface-member

I have an interface like this

```
interface IFoo
{
    protected abstract int Compute();
    int ComputeValue()
    {
        return Compute();
    }
}
```

The idea being that `Compute` computes some value and `ComputeValue` maybe does some checks and then calls `Compute` to fetch the actual value. However, I now wonder how to implement this interface in an abstract class. I can do it like this

```
abstract class Bar : IFoo
{
    public abstract int Compute();
}
```

but I dont want `Compute` to be called directly. However, when I try to implement it explicitly, e.g.

```
abstract class Bar : IFoo
{
    abstract int IFoo.Compute();
}
```

I cannot define it as abstract in the abstract class `Bar`, which is what I want. Of course, I could do something like

```
abstract class Bar : IFoo
{
    protected abstract int Compute();

    int IFoo.Compute()
    {
        return Compute();
    }
}
```

But I wonder is there a more elegant way of doing this without the additional extra method?

Comment: Don't put it in the interface, if it is only an implementation detail of the (abstract) class. The interface defines the _public_ contract

Comment: Given that interfaces can have default methods, I would argue that they define more than just the public contracts. While I would generally agree, in my specific case this is by far the more elegant solution.

Comment: Default methods are still part of the _public_ contract, the only difference is that they come with an implementation and can be used as mixins.

Comment: @AILogic _"Given that interfaces can have default methods, I would argue that they define more than just the public contracts"_ - that's why personally I hugely dislike this feature which was introduced in C# 8 I would argue mainly for the sake of compatibility with  java. So I would recommend to avoid using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much you can do here. Though according toto the [draft spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#the-most-specific-override-rule) it was considered at some point to allow the support for explicit interface abstract overrides in classes (also see the [reabstraction](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#reabstraction) part):

> Because we support explicit abstract overrides in interfaces, we could do so in classes as well

```cs
abstract class E : IA, IB, IC // ok
{
    abstract void IA.M();
}
```

> Open issue: should we support explicit interface abstract overrides in classes?

But it seems it was not followed through - see [LDM-2019-03-27 Notes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/3c8559f186d4c5df5d1299b0eaa4e139ae130ab6/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-03-27.md#explicit-interface-abstract-overrides-in-classes):

> **Explicit interface abstract overrides in classes**
> Allow abstract interface implementions in a class as well? Not an abstract class method implementing an interface method.

So either remove the `Compute` from the interface or use your current approach.